# What is the meaning of $\Bbb E$?

Tags: notation, expected-value, machine-learning

I do not have a strong math background and I have come across the symbol  in some equations in Machine Learning.

For example, the following equation in [Mnih et al 2013](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5602.pdf):
$$Q^∗(s, a) = \max_\Pi \Bbb E [R_t|s_t = s, a_t = a, π]$$

Or this equation in the [CycleGAN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10593.pdf):
$$ℒ_{GAN}(G, D_Y, X, Y) = \Bbb E_{y~p_{data}(y)}[\log D_Y(y)] + _{x~p_{data}(x)}[\log(1-D_Y(G(x))]$$

Can someone please help me understand the meaning of $\Bbb E$? (I'm sorry for bad English, it isn't my first language)

Comment: It looks like it means "expected value" but absent detailed context it is hard to know for sure.

Comment: Thank you, I've added links if anybody needs them.  It is really confusing me.

Comment: Indeed, the first reference clearly refers to "maximum expected return"

Comment: For the first reference, at the bottom of page 2: "expected return."   At the top of page 3: "expected value."  The E most likely stands for "expectation." (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value), known informally as the mean or (ambiguously) as "the average". For a discrete random variable, it's the sum of the possible values a variable can take multiplied by the probability of that value occurring, e.g. $\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x\text{P}(X=x)$.

The pipe character $|$ indicates conditional expectation e.g. $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=10)$ means "the average value of $X$ in situations where $Y=10$".

Comment: What is the meaning of the equal signs inside of [...] in the top equation?

Comment: The normal meaning - there's a pipe character before it, to indicate the conditional expectation I mentioned. It means "the average value of $R_t$ given that $s_t=s$, $a_t = a$ and $\pi$" (the last being shorthand for something given in earlier context).